# Is Jimmi Lee Jackson's Eulogy accurate as presented in Selma?

Tags: historical-accuracy, selma

I'm trying to determine how historically accurate the speech from the movie Selma (2014) given by Martin Luther King, Jr. at Jimmi Lee Jackson's funeral is, but I can't find a transcript of the actual eulogy online anywhere that isn't behind a login. The only source I've found is at Standford University but is protected behind a login/password.

The footnotes in [this article](https://kinginstitute.stanford.edu/encyclopedia/jackson-jimmie-lee) refer to *King, Eulogy for Jimmie Lee Jackson, 3 March 1965, MMFR.* but the MMFR link takes you to Stanford University login screen.

The speech as presented in the film can be seen here: